# Simulate button style of standard UIAlertView buttons

Tags: ios5

We need to implement custom buttons in a `UIAlertView`. The reason is: You can choose "Cancel" (which dismisses the alert view) or you can choose "Continue" which starts a rather long-running update process. So, the two buttons are replaced with one "Cancel" button, so that the user is able to stop the running process.

Adding a standard `UIButton` simply renders them with blue border and white background, just as a normal button in a normal view looks like. But is there a way to get them look like the buttons a normal `UIAlertView` provides (like dark blue and with a gradient for the non-destructive choice)?